# Having a problem in MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel

I'm Trying to solve this error but not getting any proper solution for this as i'm beginner in the laravel, Please help with the code..
error--> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6Jhn.png)

Thank You

This is my Web.php file

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('user',function(){
return view('user');
});
Route::get('user/register',['uses'=> 'usercontroller@create']);
Route::post('/user',['uses'=> 'usercontroller@store']);
```

Register.blade.php

```
<form method="POST" method="/user">
     {{  csrf_field()  }}
    name<input type="text" name="name">
    email<input type="email" name="email">
    pass<input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="register">
</form>
```

UserController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
class usercontroller extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        return view('register');
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        User::create($request->all());
        return 'Sucess';
        return $request->all();
    }
}
```

Comment: Case sensitivity perhaps?

Answer (score 7):

You have a mistake in your form tag (the second `method` should be `action`):

Change

```
<form method="POST" method="/user">
```

to

```
<form method="POST" action="/user">
```

Comment: Thank You so much, i have been trying this from last 3hrs

Comment: Would you please mark the answer as correct one for others with the same problem?